# What is preferred? Creating a statistics or creating a non clustered filtered index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table Customers, in which one of the columns is Country. There are very few international customers and hence 90% of the rows have null values for this column. There is a stored procedure to get the international customers (select ... from Customers where Country is not null).

I want to optimize the performance of this stored procedure. What is the best option i have: create a non clustered filtered index or create a filtered statistics ?
Also i would be thankful if someone could explain to me how statistics object is different frm indexes. Until now i thought statistics are created automatically when we create indexes.

Thanks

Comment: 90% have null? So 90% of your customers come from no country? You deal with aliens from outer space? It should not be null (which indicates per SQL standard "unknown") but your own country.

Comment: @TomTom : thats how the table is designed.. :) I didnt design the table.

Comment: I have to accomplish this with min impact to front end application

Answer (score 0):

Traditional indexes in SQL Server are b-tree structures that provide efficient access to rows based on key value and/or ordering.  Filtered indexes reduce the number of rows that are stored in the b-tree index, thus providing further efficiencies.

SQL Server maintains statistical information about key value distribution for all b-tree indexes so that it can more accurately estimate the number of qualifying rows.  This information is used by the cost-based optimizer to generate the most efficient execution plan for the query, and aid in decisions about whether to use or not use an index for a particular query.

Statistics do not have b-tree structures to facilitate locating data.  However, they do provide cardinality statistics that the optimizer can use to develop more accurate row count estimates, resulting in more efficient query plans.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd start with the filtered statistic and see if that provides "good enough" performance for your queries. Since they're not maintained transactionally (i.e. they're not changed with every insert/update/delete operation), they're cheaper from an OLTP standpoint. You may find that you do need an index merely for the data access path, though.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see much of a use in creating filtered statistics "alone". I would rather suggest a Non Clustered Filtered Index.

Why?

1. If SQL Server runs a query for which it needs some statistics information and if it does not have it, it creates it. So all those statistics with _WA_XXXXXXX format are automatically created by SQL Server.
2. Just having statistics is not much of a use if it is not backed by an index. With the help of statistics information, the optimizer would know the selectivity for the data. Great!! but the problem is nothing can be done about it.

**Why?,** because there is no index to get the data in an optimal way. So creation of a filtered index will lead to creation of a filtered statistics. Depending on quality of the definition of index, it would mostly do index seeks. Leading to less IO, less time, less locking and blocking etc.

Now given that you have the statistics information, **there are some problems with filtered statsitics that you need to keep in mind** and do something about it. Filtered statistics soon **get outdated** due to they way statistics information is updated by SQL Server algorithm. In addition to creation of filtered NC index, it would be helpful if you have a job setup to udpate the filtered statistics on regular basis.

To know more about filtered statistics outdate issue, read the blog from Kimberley Tripp. Super knowledge experts in SQL Server world!

http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/filtered-indexes-and-filtered-stats-might-become-seriously-out-of-date/